# Algorithm for traversing Int Sets

Tags: algorithm, scala

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask such a question. I will just give it a shot.

Problem:

Assume `val threshold: Int` and `val size: Int`.

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to traverse all possible `x: Set[Int]` where `x.sum < threshold` and `x.size == n`. Only Ints greater than 0 should be considered. This is of course a finite number of possibilities.

I have already tried to develop one, but even for smaller inputs it takes forever.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide your sample code?

Comment: So you have a Traversable[Set[Int]] ?

Comment: It's more like a Set[Set[Int]] in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate them recursively quite easily. Here's some code in Python that does it, but it should translate directly to Scala.

```
def sets(n, threshold, atleast=1):
    if threshold <= n * (n + atleast * 2 - 1) // 2: return
    if n == 0:
        yield []
        return
    for i in xrange(atleast, threshold):
        for s in sets(n - 1, threshold - i, i + 1):
            yield [i] + s

print list(sets(4, 15))
```

Comment: Looks promising, i will give it a try soon.

Comment: In the case where `if threshold <= n * (n + atleast * 2 - 1)` what should be returned? I don't quite understand it, since I have to yield some Set[Set[Int]].

Comment: @Kigyo that condition captures the idea that if the threshold is too low, or n too big, then there's _no_ sets of ints that satisfy the condition. (The expression is sum(i=atleast to atleast + n - 1)i < threshold). So it just returns without yielding any sets.

Answer (score 0):

I will just post my implementation of the mentioned algorithm in Scala if someone is interested:

```
def generatePossibilities(n: Int, threshold: Int) = {
    def sets(n: Int, threshold: Int, atleast: Int = 1) : Set[Set[Int]] = {
      if(threshold <= n * (n + atleast * 2 - 1) / 2) {
        Set.empty[Set[Int]]
      } else if(n == 0) {
        Set(Set.empty[Int])
      } else {
        (for(i <- atleast until threshold;
             s <- sets(n - 1, threshold - i, i + 1)) yield s + i)(collection.breakOut)
      }
    }
    sets(n, threshold)
}
```

Comment: The case `n=0, threshold=0` is wrong. You removed a condition from my code, which both captures this edge-case (which perhaps isn't important), but also eliminates a lot of recursive calls that won't produce results. For example, try (n=100, threshold=5051) with and without the extra clause.

Comment: Without knowing Scala, I suspect the missing code is `if (threshold <= n * (n + atleast * 2 - 1) / 2) { Set.empty[Set[int]] }`

Comment: Ok thx. Now i understand what you mean. I thought it was just a general check for the initial `n` and `treshold`. It also worked without it. Edited my answer.